Publish a python project via github
I uploaded a python project in github. Now I cannot publish it and getting error.
Here is the code in github
https://github.com/talat-mahmud-osman-goni/Portfolio.github.io
in website link https://talat-mahmud-osman-goni.github.io/Portfolio.github.io/
I am getting this error:
404
File not found
The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.
If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL as well as any file    permissions.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.
Read the full documentation for more information about using GitHub Pages.

On https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site#creating-your-site there is "3. Create the entry file for your site. GitHub Pages will look for an index.html, index.md, or README.md file as the entry file for your site."

GitHub Pages unfortunately doesn't support Python, it only supports static sites.
